# Link is not working Well

Tags: asp.net

this is my link in my page

asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Add 
                    Record /asp:HyperLink

with VS2008 it is fine but with IIS it creates the problem like

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404.

my directory to view.aspx page and default.aspx page is same which library.

also the path changes form

http://localhost/library/View.aspx
to 
http://localhost/Default.aspx

is anybody help me where the problem is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the link

```
asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/library/Default.aspx">Add Record
```

Instead of

```
asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Add Record
```

The "~" gets the root folder for the application. You don't want that, you want the root + `/library/` and then the page, `Default.aspx`.

Comment: Thanks for resolving the problem

Comment: It should work the same; what happens? Also, note that if it's just in the same directory, you can simply have `NavigateURL="default.aspx"`. This assumes that the current page is in the same directory as `default.aspx`.